# JMF - Extracting a Frame from a Video File

Tags: java, video, jmf

I've looked around the Java and JMF documentation, but can't find a solution to this question. Keep in mind I'm very new to Java (but have experience in C/C++).

I would like to take an MPEG video file and extract a particular frame from it (or rather read all the frames into memory as images). From what I've read, JMF is the way to go but I'm not entirely sure.

Could you please point me in the right direction so I can find out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked with JMF previously, I would recommend you look to an API like [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com/) for this functionality.  JMF was good for what it did, but it was abandoned long ago, and is unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks. Is Xuggle third-party or is it maintained by Oracle?

Comment: 3rd party, but at least it is maintained.

Comment: Xuggle is fine for 32 bit java, but not compatible with 64 bit java on Windows

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I confirm I can't use Xuggle that I see everyone recommending. Would you recommend JMF then?

Comment: *"Would you recommend JMF then?"*  **Then** I would, **now** I wouldn't.